# expressing permutations in terms of generators

Tags: gr.group-theory

Suppose I have $G < S_n,$ with generators $g_1, \dots, g_k,$ and I have some $g\in G.$ I want to write $g$ as a word in the generators. How hard is this, computationally? And is there a simple algorithm someone can point me to? I assume Gap and Magma have this built in...

Comment: http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap39.html#X7E19F92284F6684E

Comment: See in particular the section *39.5 Expressing Group Elements as Words in Generators*

Comment: It is a difficult problem in general, if you are looking for a word that is close to being of shortest possible length. The Rubik cube group is a notoriously hard example to solve completely. For many applications, a straight line program for the group element is good enough and that can be found efficienjtly. More precisely, you can extend the given set of generators to a set of *strong generators*, and use those for your word.

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't really care about the "shortest" aspect. Is the straight line program algorithm in your book?

Comment: The Schreier-Sims algorithm and the like are explained in detail in the *Handbook of Computational Group Theory*. -- I think this is what you need, isn't it?

Comment: @Francesco Polizzi: To cite the GAP-Manual: "Therefore this function should not be used when the group $G$ has more than a few million elements."

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta: well, no information on the size of $G$ was provided by the question :-)

Comment: I should perhaps mention that I have had some e-mail discussions with Igor Rivin, and it turned out that we could find a satisfactory solution to the special case of the problem that he wanted to solve.

Comment: @Jan-ChristophSchlage-Puchta that limitation is for finding a shortest possible word, and does not apply if you just want to find *some* word, which can be done in GAP using EpimorphismFromFreeGroup plus PreImagesRepresentative

Answer (score 6):

In general the problem is very difficult. There has been quite some work on the diameter of the Cayleygraph of $S_n$, the best results being due to Helfgott-Seress for the general case, and Helfgott-Seress-Zuk for the random case. However, as far as I know these proofs are non-constructive in the sense that they only show the existence of a word of small length, but do not give an algorithm to find this word.

One approach that sometimes works is to generate short words in the given generators, until you find a word you understand so well that the representation problem becomes trivial. For example, suppose you can find an element which contains a single 2-cycle and no other cycle of even length. Taking powers you get an explicit description of a transposition. Then you construct a 2-transitive subset, and get a representation for any transposition. Finally write the element $g$ as a product of transpositions.

Bratus and Pak (J. Symbolic Comput. 29 (2000), 33-57) used this approach to give a fast randomized algorithm to find an isomorphism between a black box group and $S_n$. I used it to give an algorithm which for almost all $\pi, \sigma$ finds in polynomial running time a word of length $O(n^3\log n)$ representing any given $g$ ( Combinatorica 32 (2012), 309–323).

Comment: Appendix B of Helfgott-Seress-Zuk sketches out how to convert the main theorem of the paper into an algorithm: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.6742.pdf

Comment: Ah, I only looked at the "construction of small cycles" part. So "As far as I know" was not that far.